# AWS Athena: line 11:1: mismatched input 'PARTITIONED'. Expecting: 'COMMENT', 'WITH', <EOF> while creating table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to create an empty table which contains some columns with determined datatypes in S3 with a command launched in Athena, but it is throwing me the following error:

```
line 11:1: mismatched input 'PARTITIONED'. Expecting: 'COMMENT', 'WITH', <EOF>
```

The query I'm executing is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boards_raw_fields_v1 (
  "uuid" bigint,
  "source" string,
  "raw_company_name" string,
  "raw_contract_type" string,
  "raw_employment_type" string,
  "raw_working_hours_type" string,  
  "raw_all_locations" array<string>, 
  "raw_categories" array<string>, 
  "raw_industry" string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  "year" string, 
  "month" string, 
  "day" string, 
  "hour" string, 
  "version" bigint)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://my-data/datalake-raw/boards/raw-fields/v1'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='snappy', 
  'projection.enabled'='false', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

In the URI:

```
s3://my-data/datalake-raw/boards/raw-fields/v1
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: All the folders are currently created except the last one `v1`

What am I doing wrong here in the process of creating the table?

Comment: The same query worked for me after removing all the double quotes.

Comment: Yes, actually it works by doing that

Comment: `uuid` bigint, 
  `source` string,

Comment: Yeah, an actual UUID cannot be mapped to a bigint type as its a hexadecimal number.